# Downloading multiple images in Python

Tags: python, download

I am downloading multiple images in python, the problem is only the last image in the loop is being downloaded

```
for imgRec in imgresult:

    temp = os.path.join(cwd,'photo_dump',str(fbid))
    if os.path.exists(temp):
        shutil.rmtree(temp)     

    try:
        os.makedirs(temp)
    except OSError:
        pass

    tmp_filename = imgRec[3].split('/')[-1]



    img_link = imgRec[3]

    if(downimg(temp,img_link,tmp_filename)):
        print 'Done'
```

and code for function is

```
def downimg(temp,img_link,tmp_filename,count):
    tm = None
    im = None
    tm = urllib.urlopen(img_link).read()
    im = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(tm))          
    im.verify()

    res[count] = urllib.urlretrieve(img_link,os.path.join(temp,tmp_filename))


    return res[count]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the directory "temp", which pictures are downloaded into, is removed at each iteration of for loop. 
If you need to download all images into a single directory, the code that creates the folder should be before the loop.

```
temp = os.path.join(cwd,'photo_dump',str(fbid))
if os.path.exists(temp):
    shutil.rmtree(temp)     

try:
    os.makedirs(temp)
except OSError:
    pass

for imgRec in imgresult:

    tmp_filename = imgRec[3].split('/')[-1]
    img_link = imgRec[3]

    if(downimg(temp,img_link,tmp_filename)):
        print 'Done'
```

If you need a directory per image, change "fbid" inside the loop.